# onContextItemSelected Error

Tags: android

I having some difficulty implementing a context menu into my android application. My first problem was I was trying to implement OnCreateContextMenu inside of OnCreate but I kept getting an error saying:

> void is an invalid type for the variable onCreateContextMenu

I fixed this problem by putting `onCreateContextMenu` outside of OnCreate. Now my problem lies with `OnContextItemSelected`. My error occurs on the line: `public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem menu)`. The errors are:

> - implements android.view.View.OnLongClickListener.onLongClick
> - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody

Here is the code:

```
BaconStripsButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
                 {
                 if (item.itemId() = 0)
                 {
                     Toast ringtone = Toast.makeText(startingPoint.this, "Ringtone added Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                 return true;
                 }
                return false;
                 }
            }
        });
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks, Justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use onContextItemSelected Inside onlongClick of button.Just Override OnContextItemSelected(); and register ContextMenu to btn.No need to setOnlongClickListener.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
 super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
 inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
 }
```

Then override

```
@Override

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
switch (item.getItemId()) {
case R.id.edit:
editNote(info.id);
return true;
case R.id.delete:
deleteNote(info.id);
return true;
 default:
 return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
 }
```

}
then finally registerContextMenu(button);

Comment: Yes thanks for the help. One other question though: I am making a soundboard app and I am wondering how I would handle each button within 'onContextItemSelected' . Depending on which button is long pressed would determine which mp3 would be added as a ringtone.

Comment: you can do it by using id of these item as use switch case to determine which item of contextmenu is selected

Comment: No I am trying to determine which was button was long pressed to show the context menu.

Comment: ask another question for this problem.as this is quite different

Answer (score 1):

You may use the ListView and implement the onCreateContextMenu in the OnCreate of the Activity.

like this:

myList.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            // add some sublist
            menu.setHeaderTitle(R.string.collect_title); 
            menu.add(0, 1, 0, R.string.delete_string);
            menu.add(0, 2, 0, R.string.move_to_project_string); 
            menu.add(0, 3, 0, R.string.move_to_action_string);
        }
    });
```